# ¿Que puedo hacer si nadie responde a mis publicaciones?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Hola a todos se que en base al título es una pregunta muy fácil de responder como lo dice el mismo stackoverflow [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), pero en las soluciones que te da si nadie responde tu pregunta por ejemplo es, ofrecer una recompensa, el problema es que no puedo ofrecer una debido a que son algo recientes y no me deja generarla e hice las preguntas aquí debido a que esperaba una pronta respuesta ya que los problemas sobre los que pregunto me impiden seguir con mi ruta de aprendizaje, yo creo que las preguntas que hice son buenas o al menos están dentro de lo que stackoverflow considera una **buena pregunta**, entonces en este caso ya que como mencione no puedo seguir aprendiendo a programar si no soluciono algunos de los errores que hice en mis publicaciones, ¿qué puedo hacer para que mas gente me ayude a solucionar mis problemas? (las preguntas están [en mi perfil de stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/253402/david-flores-garc%C3%ADa)).Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Leiste todas las ayudas sobre como mejorar tus preguntas? agregaste los errores que te dan en forma clara y completa? hiciste un seguimiento cuando te hicieron preguntas sobre tus preguntas? Este no es un sitio donde las cosas se resuelvan de forma urgente. A veces, se resuelven rapido, otras tardan mas, otras no se resuelven nunca. Este es un sitio que ayuda a dar con las soluciones, pero no siempre estan a la vista. Y no es un sitio en que las cosas se resuelvan urgente. Solo se resuelven cuando se resuelven. Algunas de tus preguntas dicen "No anda, no funciono" y no aclaran mas que eso.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi,  creo que si di los datos necesarios para que mi pregunta pueda tal vez tener una respuesta clara y mostré todos los errores que me salían

Comment: yo me he tomado el tiempo de revisar tu perfil y veo 4 preguntas que han tenido una buena recepcion y una respuesta que tambien tubo buena recepcion, en particular dependiendo de la complejidad de tu problema sera mas dificil conseguir que alguien se intereseen responderte, en el caso de laravel, la unica pregunta con 0 votos, es muy dificio darte una respuesta, tal vez en un canal de discord especializado en el tema recibas algun comentario al respecto..

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía buenas, yo he sido uno de los que te ha respondido, y la verdad no veo "demora" en el tiempo de respuesta. Generalmente las respuestas se consiguen de personas que hacen las cosas voluntariamente, por lo que si, una respuesta demora. Por eso es muy importante crear buenas preguntas.

Comment: @Excorpion si tu has sido de los que me responden y te lo agradezco mucho, lo malo es que tenía un problema el cual no me permitia seguir aprendiendo  y ya habían pasado dos dias desde que había hecho la pregunta y no había comentario o incluso vistas, termine borrando la pregunta despues de que me pasara los dos días buscando en otros lados, pero por eso preguntaba, re formulando mi pregunta ¿que podia hacer si nadie ve mis preguntas?

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero es aceptar que el mundo no gira alrededor de ti, esto evitará algunas cosas que normalmente afectan tanto a ti como a la comunidad como:

- publicar otra pregunta 99% igual a la anterior
- decir que necesitas ayuda urgente
- en general ser un vampiro de comunidades

Bajo este primer corolario, yo personalmente optaría por:

1. Editar la pregunta
2. Dividir en varias preguntas más simples
3. Editar las preguntas relacionadas
4. Pedir que alguien se tome el tiempo en el chat
5. Compartir la pregunta a potenciales respondedores
6. Preguntar en soen
7. Esperar hasta poder agregar una recompensa

### Editar la pregunta

Una buena edición de pregunta cambiará casi instantáneamente las preguntas relacionadas, puede traer a personas que se hayan suscrito a ciertas etiquetas y en general hará más fácil el responder si es mejor tu [mcve]

### Dividir en preguntas más simples

Básicamente la estrategia divide y vencerás para tratar de resolver tu problema de manera iterativa e incremental

### Editar preguntas relacionadas

Sí... da flojera, pero hará que las preguntas relacionadas sean más relevantes y te ayudará a pensar fuera de la caja

### Pedir que alguien se tome el tiempo en el chat

Los usuarios con reputación mayor a cierto número tienen acceso al chat, seguramente interactuando con ellos obtendrás retroalimentación de como mejorar tu pregunta para que obtenga mejores respuestas y tal vez hasta alguno de ellos la pudiera responder

### Compartir la pregunta

El sitio siempre ha tenido la opción de compartir tanto preguntas como respuestas para que uses el hipervínculo que genera en tus redes socialeds de preferencia (twister, feisbu, instagra, snapcha, wasaa, o cualquier otra del interné en general )<sup>1</sup>

### preguntar en SOen

Si manejas el inglés puedes preguntar tu pregunta en ese sitio en el idioma antesmencionado, tomando en cuenta que esa comunidad es un poco <strike>mam*nc1t4</strike> particular debido a su <strike>in?</strike>madurez. Las preguntas en esa comunidad tienen un promedio más rápido de respuesta.

### Esperar hasta poder agregar una recompensa

Creo que es la manera más efectiva de darle <strike>amor</strike> atención a una pregunta

<sup>1</sup> Errores ortográficos a propósito

Comment: No me parece la recomendación de acudir al chat, pues no es el medio adecuado para trabajar con código. Me ha tocado hacerlo y la experiencia es deplorable. Más aún, acudir al chat es como saltarse la fila, exigir una atención express VIP. Desagradable.

Comment: entiendo tu molestia, yo nunca lo he hecho, y sinceramente lo más probable es que no ayude yo mismo a nadie que pida ayuda mendiante el chat, pero dar ayuda ya dependerá de los demás

Comment: Como siempre, hay que aplicar criterio y no ser un Taliban del reglamento.

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que hay 2 razones fundamentales por las que las preguntas "bien" planteadas no son respondidas.

- Es muy largo y/o trabajoso reproducir el ejemplo mínimo y verificable.  Puede ser porque requiera mucho código o requiera instalaciones o  configuraciones específicas.
- No hay una comunidad suficientemente numerosa.

Para el primer punto la solución es esforzarse al máximo en construír algo reproducible y mínimo. **El hecho de que sea mínimo es fundamental**, las preguntas con mucho código, yo y muchos otros no las leemos siquiera. En este esfuerzo de simplificar el problema puede incluso surgir la solución.
Muchas veces lo que se encuentra en las preguntas "Con recompensa" son justamente problemas muy tediosos de reproducir, por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492802/cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-uid-por-qu%C3%A9-no-me-muestra-el-uid-del), independientemente de que este bien planteada o no, no la voy a leer solo por la longitud, a pesar de tener una recompensa de 100 puntos, y a pesar de que seguramente la solución sea trivial (una variable es `null` cuando no debería), es decir que captar atención con la "recompensa" no es del todo útil sin el ejemplo mínimo y verificable.

Respecto a tus preguntas, en [esta en particular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493512/problema-al-enviar-datos-ajax-php) te hacen dos comentarios solicitando `console.log` de alguna variable, ese solo hecho indica que el ejemplo podría ser reducido. El resultado de ambos `console` reducirían el problema a la mitad. Esto quiere decir que el ejemplo no es **mínimo**, y evita que muchos usuarios se interesen en responder.

Para el segundo punto, yo creo que sería conveniente hacer la pregunta en algún otro lugar donde la comunidad sea mas numerosa. SO en Inglés tiene muchísima mas atención, pero las preguntas caen rápidamente en el olvido, es fundamental otra vez el ejemplo mínimo y verificable.

Comment: Hola comente en mi respuesta los `console.log` pero literalmente no pasaba nada y eso fue lo que comente justo que no había resultado, pero de el valor de mi input si estaba todo bien y creo que igual les comente eso, despues de eso no se que mas información puedo dar

Comment: Bueno pero eso no cambia a la pregunta en si y la atención que esta recibe